# Display image using path variable in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

> How to display an image by passing a variable path to twig?

```
{% image '{{path}}' %}
    <img src="{{ asset_url }}" width=100 height=100/>
{% endimage %}
```

> The above code is not working where
> path =@Bundle/Resources/public/images/image.jpg
>
> Or how to convert variable path to asset_url?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with `asset('images/image.jpg')`?

Comment: How about `asset('bundles/yourbundlename/images/image.jpg')`?

Comment: The above code works fine. But when the given path is passed to twig page as a variable which contains the path for image to be displayed, how to display it?